# Grunt-crx plugin not creating .crx file for Chrome App

Tags: google-chrome, gruntjs, google-chrome-app

I am creating a grunt task that will create .crx file for my chrome app.
Here is my gruntfile code  for crx

crx: {

```
    appPackage: {

      src : '<%= cvars.app %>/**/*',
      dest : '<%= cvars.dist %>/',
      options :{
         "privateKey": 'app.pem' // it is my .pem for chrome app 
      }
    }
 }
```

grunt.registerTask('crx', ['crx']);

But wheh i run the command grunt crx :
it only show: Grunt and task output will also be logged to "./logs/grunt.log"
after that nothing is happening , cursor keep on blinking .

Could anyone help me out from this.
Thanks in advance.